# how can fix cors error when send POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some errors when I send post request
Please fix the error. This is simple error and I can not get the response from the server.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "https://thentic.tech/api/nfts/contract",
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',xhrFields: {cors: true},
          cors: true,
          contentType:'application/json',
          secure: true,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
          data:{ key: "yGQLF3Rd8tfWPT32vC06VF5UwrZZxsfb",
                chain_id: "97",
                name: "aaa", 
                short_name: "sdf"}, 
          success: function (data){console.log('dd')          
          }
      })
```

And the response is

GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
1.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at 1.html:6:1

please help me to fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: How is this related to cors?